# What could be the most efficient(in terms of time) algorithm to generate anagrams?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, anagram

The following is the code I came up with to find anagrams of a given string, however I found this to be really slow, when the string is really large. Is there something I can do to make this faster? Is there another algorithm that makes this kind of an operation fast?

```
def combinate(stri, comb,n,li):
    if stri == "":
        if comb not in li:
            li.append(comb)
        return
    for sdx, s in enumerate(stri):
        combinate(stri[0:sdx] + stri[sdx + 1:], comb+s,n)
```

Comment: You define `combinate` with four arguments but call it with three. And you never use one of the arguments (`n`). So I don't see how you could have tested it. Also, presumably the second argument is a string; why then do you feel the need to `copy.deepcopy` it? And what on earth is the point of `if X==False:return`? (And why not `if X: return`?). But those are minor details. The main problem is the quadratic time complexity of the uniqueness check.

Comment: @rici The point of it was to break the recursion. I didn't mention it to avoid confusion. This algorithm works, I'm simply looking for a way to run faster.

Comment: 1. Simple answer: Use a set instead of a list for the uniqueness check. 2. Better answer: use an algorithm which doesn't generate duplicates. Also: I believe the algo works but the code doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Sort characters in the string and in possible anagrams and compare sorted versions.

```
"task": "akst"
"skat": "akst"
```

Note that dictionary entry on key "akst" might contain list of anagrams as value

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for "most efficient" in time complexity, take each term and sort its characters into order, then store these in a (multi-valued) map.  Given a word you want to find anagrams for, likewise sort its characters, and look up corresponding entries in the map.  This would be O(1) for each look up, although the pre-computation is linear in the total number of terms.

I think it's safe to say that this is the best possible time complexity, but you might want to handle multi-word anagrams differently - it's likely to be impractical to do this for combinations of more than a few words (the precomputation will be very large), so you'd probably want to construct your anagram one word at a time.